# Remove childless elements (except leafs) from nested array

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, recursion, tree

I've got a table called `mappings` with `id`, `leaf`, `parent_id`, `name` and `flip_parent` columns. `parent_id` and `flip_parent` are both integers referring to the `mapping`.`id` column. `flip_parent` holds an id of a value that should be excluded from the tree. To do so I've got the following function (`$mappings` are all rows from the `mappings` table, `flipParentIds` are all values from the same table where the `flip_parent` value is not `null`)

```
private function removeFlipParents(array $mappings, array $flipParentIds)
{
    foreach ($mappings as $key => $mapping) {
        foreach ($flipParentIds as $id) {
            if ($mapping['id'] === $id['flipParent']) {
                unset($mappings[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $mappings;
}
```

After those values have been removed, I need to build a tree with the remaining data (the tree goes 5/6 levels deep), which is done with the following piece of code;

```
private function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId)
{
    $branch = [];

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
       if ($element['parentId'] == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            } else {
                $element['children'] = [];
            }
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

In this case `elements` is the same array as `$mappings`, but without those flip parents. The result of this function is returned as a JSON response and handled by Javascript to build a tree. The returned JSON has a structure similar to this;

```
[{
    "id": 1, "name": "Node 1", "children": [{
      "id": 2, "name": "Node 1.1", "children": [{
        "id": 4, "name": "Node 1.1.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 1000, "name": "GL1", "code": "0100"
        }, {
          "id": 1001, "name": "GL2", "code": "0200"
        }]
      }, {
        "id": 5, "name": "Node 1.1.2", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 2000, "name": "GL3", "code": "0300"
        }, {
          "id": 2001, "name": "GL4", "code": "0400"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 3, "name": "Node 1.2", "children": [{
        "id": 6, "name": "Node 1.2.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 3000, "name": "GL5", "code": "0500"
        }, {
          "id": 3001, "name": "GL6", "code": "0600"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 7, "name": "Node 2", "children": [{
      "id": 8, "name": "Node 2.1", "children": [{
        "id": 9, "name": "Node 2.1.1", "leaf": true, "children": [], "gls": [{
          "id": 4000, "name": "GL7", "code": "0700"
        }, {
          "id": 4001, "name": "GL8", "code": "0800"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

To build the tree in JS I've got the following two functions

```
parseNodes(nodes)
{
    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.style.listStyleType = 'none';
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
        const parsedNode = this.parseNode(node);
        if (parsedNode) {
            ul.appendChild(parsedNode);
        }
    });
    return ul;
}

parseNode(node)
{
    if (node.name && node.name !== '') {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = node.leaf ? 'leaf' : 'parent';
        li.setAttribute('data-mapping-id', node.id);

        if (node.parentId) {
            li.setAttribute('data-parent-id', node.parentId);
        }

        li.innerHTML = node.name;

        if (node.children) {
            li.appendChild(this.parseNodes(node.children));
        }

        return li;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This all works perfectly fine, but I now want to remove childless, non-leaf nodes from the tree, as only the leafs will actually be usable. I don't know at what level the childless nodes are, and not all childless nodes are at the same level.

To do so I've written a recursive PHP function, which is called **after** `removeFlipParents` and `buildTree` (this needs to be done as I need the tree structure to check whether branches have children of not);

```
private function removeChildlessBranches(array $nodes)
{
    foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
        if (empty($node['children']) && !$node['leaf']) {
            unset($nodes[$key]);
        } else {
            $this->removeChildlessBranches($node['children']);
        }
    }

    return $nodes;
}
```

This kinda does what I want it to do as it removes all childless root nodes that aren't leafs, but it doesn't go to the 2nd level and beyond. It also changes the structure of `$nodes`. Without the `removeChildlessBranches` call the JSON is wrapped in an array (`[{"id": 1, "name": "Node 1", ...}]`) and I can iterate over it in the `parseNodes` function, but if I do use the `removeChildlessBranches` call, `$nodes` no longer is wrapped in an array (`{"id": 1, "name": "Node 1", ...}`) and can't be iterated over.

So my two questions are, how can I make `removeChildlessBranches` actually recursive, and how can I make it so it doesn't change the structure of `$nodes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a copy of the `$node['children']` array on this line `$this->removeChildlessBranches($node['children']);` (If you haven't heard of it before lookup pass by reference and pass by value). So any subsequent changes are being made to that copy and not your original array (which is also a copy). The results of the changes are then being thrown away as you're not doing anything with them.

You could fix that issue by changing the line to this `$nodes[$key]['children'] = $this->removeChildlessBranches($node['children']);`.

Be aware however, that you may now have a node which has no children and is not a leaf but will not be removed correctly as you've already trimmed at that level. Trimming out children first and then unsetting should give you the desired result:

```php
private function removeChildlessBranches(array $nodes)
{
    foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
        $nodes[$key]['children'] = $this->removeChildlessBranches($node['children']);

        if (empty($nodes[$key]['children']) && !$nodes[$key]['leaf']) {
            unset($nodes[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $nodes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work the way I want it to! One more thing though, the function still returns an object of objects, while I need it to be an array of objects. How can I enforce that?

Comment: The PHP function will return an array of arrays. It's actually the json_encode function which is causing you trouble. Since you're unsetting array values you now have "missing" array indices. JavaScript doesn't support out of order array keys so the only solution for json_encode is to encode the array as an object. Once we know and understand the cause the we can get the desired result by fixing the array indices by using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php so we end up with `json_encode(array_values($nodes));`

Comment: Actually, there is an edge case with that approach. `children` may still be encoded as objects as they may still have out of order keys. To make things cleaner and fix that issue change the last line of the `removeChildlessBranches` function to be `return array_values($nodes);` that way you're guaranteed to have your arrays come out in order.

Comment: That's what I've done now and it works perfectly, thanks!